# finding edges in networkx that meet a certain criteria

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a [networkx digraph](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes.digraph.html) with attributes on the nodes, and I want to find all edges where a particular node attribute is different. Is there a way to do this automatically, or do I have to iterate with `edge_iter(data=True)` and find them myself?

Comment: What do you mean by "a particular node attribute is different"?  Can you provide a concrete example?  My initial intuition would be to iterate over those nodes that have the different value.

Comment: ah - do you mean those edges for which the attribute for one node is different than for the other?

Comment: Assuming you want to return an edge if attribute of node 1 != attribute of node 2, then I don't think you can do better than taking the iterator for the edges and only yielding those with attributes not equal.  The only alternative I would suggest would be if there are only a small number of attribute values.  So you could make it a multipartite graph and somehow throw out edges within a particular component.  But fundamentally, I think the answer is "find them yourself".

Comment: "do you mean those edges for which the attribute for one node is different than for the other?" yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this but it is pretty simple:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1,color='red')
G.add_node(2,color='red')
G.add_node(3,color='blue')
G.add_node(4,color='blue')

G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(3,4)])

for (u,v) in G.edges_iter():
    if G.node[u]['color'] != G.node[v]['color']:
        print u,v
```