# Build a graph with edges' lengths displayed using distance matrix

Tags: csv, numpy, matrix, graph, networkx

Suppose I have a csv ('matrix.csv') file with a symmetric matrix of edges' length of a graph:

```
,a,b,c,d
a,nan,0.3,0.2,nan
b,0.3,nan,nan,nan
c,0.2,nan,nan,0.1
d,nan,nan,0.1,nan
```

As an output I would like to get a picture of the graph, in which there are 3 edges, connecting a with b, a with c, and d with c, with distances written on those edges.

So far I have a code that reads the csv file into numpy object using pandas dataframe object(I know, it is stupid, but from_pandas_dataframe didn't work with networkx)

```
import matplotlib
import networkx as nx
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('matrix.csv', sep=',',index_col=0, decimal=",")
numpyMatrix = df.as_matrix()
G1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(numpyMatrix)
G = nx.Graph(numpyMatrix)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), node_color='salmon')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

But the code also plots all other edges (which are 'nan' values).
Another question is how to plot only the set of edges with the length greater than 0.1, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you cast the dataframe to a matrix you can use the Pandas .fillna() method to replace the nans with 0. Then note that your matrix has 0s and string versions of the other floats. You can then case the matrix entries to floats using the numpy array .astype() method.

```
numpyMatrix = df.fillna(0).as_matrix()
numpyMatrix = numpyMatrix.astype(float)
```

If you want to further filter your edges check out:
[finding edges in networkx that meet a certain criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161266/finding-edges-in-networkx-that-meet-a-certain-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the second part of the question:

```
import matplotlib
import networkx as nx
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mat.csv', sep=';',index_col=0, decimal=",")
l = list(df)
G = nx.Graph()
for item in l:
    for item0 in l:
        if l.index(item0) < l.index(item) and df[item][item0] > 0.1:
            G.add_edge(item, item0, weight=df[item][item0])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), node_color='salmon')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Basically, here you read the csv file, then (assume symmetric matrix) for every pair of nodes you decide (not) to draw an edge between two nodes, if a certain condition holds( here it is df[item][item0] > 0.1, i.e. the length(weight) of an edge is greater than 0.1).